# Ethernet problem, Not receiving packets

Tags: networking, network-manager, ethernet

I'm having problems with the connection of my Ethernet.

Even when the interface is UP:

```
enp57s0f1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
link/ether 80:fa:5b:6a:a5:d4 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

I'm able to send  packets but I'm not able to receive them

```
enp57s0f1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 80:fa:5b:6a:a5:d4 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    RX: bytes  packets  errors  dropped overrun mcast   
    0          0        0       0       0       0       
    TX: bytes  packets  errors  dropped carrier collsns 
    340265     1877     0       0       0       0
```

The logs of the network manager usually show this:

```
NetworkManager[1033]: <info>  [1570450750.2616] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_GLOBAL
NetworkManager[1033]: <info>  [1570450888.9975] policy: auto-activating connection 'Wired_connection_1'
NetworkManager[1033]: <info>  [1570450889.0014] device (enp57s0f1): Activation: starting connection 'Wired_connection_1' (21a7b2ee-5094-3939-9513-c138d8b2edab)
NetworkManager[1033]: <info>  [1570450889.0024] device (enp57s0f1): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
NetworkManager[1033]: <info>  [1570450889.0031] device (enp57s0f1): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
NetworkManager[1033]: <info>  [1570450889.0040] device (enp57s0f1): state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
NetworkManager[1033]: <info>  [1570450889.0045] dhcp4 (enp57s0f1): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
NetworkManager[1033]: <info>  [1570450889.0066] dhcp4 (enp57s0f1): dhclient started with pid 10891
dhclient[10891]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp57s0f1 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 3 (xid=0x58746c62)
dhclient[10891]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp57s0f1 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 7 (xid=0x58746c62)
dhclient[10891]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp57s0f1 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 14 (xid=0x58746c62)
dhclient[10891]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp57s0f1 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 15 (xid=0x58746c62)
dhclient[10891]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp57s0f1 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 18 (xid=0x58746c62)
NetworkManager[1033]: <warn>  [1570450934.0052] dhcp4 (enp57s0f1): request timed out
NetworkManager[1033]: <info>  [1570450934.0054] dhcp4 (enp57s0f1): state changed unknown -> timeout
NetworkManager[1033]: <info>  [1570450934.0391] dhcp4 (enp57s0f1): canceled DHCP transaction, DHCP client pid 10891
NetworkManager[1033]: <info>  [1570450934.0392] dhcp4 (enp57s0f1): state changed timeout -> done
NetworkManager[1033]: <info>  [1570450934.0409] device (enp57s0f1): state change: ip-config -> failed (reason 'ip-config-unavailable', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
NetworkManager[1033]: <warn>  [1570450934.0431] device (enp57s0f1): Activation: failed for connection 'Wired_connection_1'
NetworkManager[1033]: <info>  [1570450934.0439] device (enp57s0f1): state change: failed -> disconnected (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
```

If I check the status of copper cables everything looks ok

```
Interface Speed Local pair Pair length        Remote pair Pair status
--------- ----- ---------- ------------------ ----------- --------------------
Gi0/3     1000M Pair A     41   +/- 10 meters Pair B      Normal              
                Pair B     41   +/- 10 meters Pair A      Normal              
                Pair C     41   +/- 10 meters Pair D      Normal              
                Pair D     41   +/- 10 meters Pair C      Normal
```

The computer seems to be connected when I search the status of the interfaces in the swicth

```
Gi0/3     A02 - Workstation  connected    20         a-full a-1000 10/100/1000BaseTX
```

Also the switch knows the computer's mac address:

```
           Mac Address Table
-------------------------------------------

Vlan    Mac Address       Type        Ports
----    -----------       --------    -----
  20    80fa.5b6a.a5d4    DYNAMIC     Gi0/3
```

The switch seems to send the packets to the computer but they never arrive

```
GigabitEthernet0/3 is up, line protocol is up (connected) 
  Description: A02 - Workstation
  MTU 1500 bytes, BW 1000000 Kbit/sec, DLY 10 usec, 
     reliability 255/255, txload 1/255, rxload 1/255
  Encapsulation ARPA, loopback not set
  Keepalive set (10 sec)
  Full-duplex, 1000Mb/s, media type is 10/100/1000BaseTX
  input flow-control is off, output flow-control is unsupported 
  ARP type: ARPA, ARP Timeout 04:00:00
  Last input never, output 00:00:07, output hang never
  Last clearing of "show interface" counters 2w0d
  Input queue: 0/75/0/0 (size/max/drops/flushes); Total output drops: 1886
  Queueing strategy: fifo
  Output queue: 0/40 (size/max)
  5 minute input rate 1000 bits/sec, 1 packets/sec
  5 minute output rate 0 bits/sec, 0 packets/sec
     5369157 packets input, 905525711 bytes, 0 no buffer
     Received 27215 broadcasts (20150 multicasts)
     0 runts, 0 giants, 0 throttles 
     0 input errors, 0 CRC, 0 frame, 0 overrun, 0 ignored
     0 watchdog, 20150 multicast, 0 pause input
     0 input packets with dribble condition detected
     7547468 packets output, 3260967444 bytes, 0 underruns
     0 output errors, 0 collisions, 0 interface resets
     0 unknown protocol drops
     0 babbles, 0 late collision, 0 deferred
     0 lost carrier, 0 no carrier, 0 pause output
     0 output buffer failures, 0 output buffers swapped out
```

Finally, for some reason, if I boot up my machine with my Ethernet cable plugged in, my wired connection will not work: even if I replug it, even if I tell my laptop to forget the network. However, if I boot up my system with my Ethernet cable unplugged, and then plug it it after it lands on the desktop, it works just fine.
The Wi-Fi works perfectly fine regardless.

Comment: I think you mean "packets" (TCP/IP packets), not "packages". Install the `wireshark` package to watch the TCP/IP packets flow. Does `ping` work both ways? (Can the switch `ping` you?).

Comment: Is this system connected to a Cisco switch?  Is the port it's plugged into an Access port or a Trunk port?  If it's an access port have you activated Portfast yet?  This sometimes happens when you attempt to get an IP address but time out because the link negotiation for spanning tree is still happening - portfast bypasses the trunk detection and allows 'instant link' to endpoint systems that aren't trunks.

Comment: @Waltinator thank you for the correction with "packets".  After I boot up my system with my Ethernet cable unplugged, I'm able to ping both ways, but when I make a soft boot the switch can not ping me because Im not even able to get the IP

Comment: @ThomasWard, The Portfast is configure as "spanning-tree portfast edge" that is the configuration for all pcs in the network but there is only one that is not working, the problem started after switches change, so it is possible to be related with this but I don't discard the possibility that the problem is also related with a Linux kernel update.

Comment: Look at `ip route` in each of your problem states. Try turning WiFi OFF/DISABLED while you test wired. It looks like you get no response to your DHCP broadcast "Who has `80:fa:5b:6a:a5:d4`?", but `wireshark` would let you see all.